# Authorization on web page

Tags: javascript, authentication, web

Good time of day!
I am wondering about right way to implement authorization on  abstract  website.

I have a server on which mysql is running. And in one of it's databases it has pairs: login + password.

Also I have a web page with "sign in form". User's input (in plain text) i need to transmit to the back-end and check it over. This plain text delivery is pain in my neck.

I know that there are various modern technologies such as openID and OAuth. I cant use them. I need to do tiny web application.

I was thinking about using salt with hashing on the destination server, but came to a conclusion that it is useless against sniffing network. Then I decided to modify with some instruments login+password pair on the client side. 
But the only way how I can accomplish that is with client javascript, that can be easily read by someone and do all steps to prepare his value that would be fatal to my auth  system ).

I am really interesting in theory, not a list of ready solutions but explanations of how it is right to do. But ready solutions are welcome, too.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to use SSL to encrypt the connection?

Comment: Don't forget to **properly** hash the password in your database.  Use a key-derivation function like PBKDF2.  **Do not** store plaintext passwords in your database.

Comment: No i have not tried to use SSL. I have not because i can't afford it.

Comment: Well SSL is a must for any secure page. StartSSL is free for a TLD, but if you are having financial troubles with your web app then there are bigger problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep it simple I would suggest you keep your standard login form (plain text POST) and force to use SSL when posting (i.e. use https instead of http in the post url). This way, nobody can sniff the user/password information.

Once you confirm the user/password is valid, then you use cookies to store a session id and keep using the session id from the cookie. If you still want to make sure nobody hijacks your session id, you should keep using SSL in the communication with your server from then on. This second part is pretty much standard even in all these authentication frameworks (they rely on cookies for storing the temporary session token).

Comment: Is SSL the only solution? I feel no. For example ssh keys: they have private and public pieces. And public piece is really public and i can show it everybody. But how to implement encoding with public key? and decoding it with private? 
SSL cert is too expensive for such a small project that would be never subject of real security attack. 
But thank you for your answer.

Comment: @PavelShvechikov: SSL is the only way to properly guarantee data confidentiality and server authentication.  If you're worried about cost, [use a free CA](http://www.startssl.com/).

Comment: Thanks! I am surprised, that there are free CA. Really. 
And you are right indeed that SSL is a point to dig in. 
but it is interesting how ssh make absolutely (if using elliptics curve keys) private (there is no proof of concept about this sort of keys as far as I know) connections.

Comment: @PavelShvechikov: Commercial SSL certificates are extremely cheap. In my projects I bought SSL certs for as cheap as $7 (i.e. at Godaddy). If this is still too expensive you can always create your own certificates. The only issue is that client browsers will show a warning telling them about the untrusted certificate, but it will work if they acknowledge it. SSH and SSL both use public-private key pairs, however, you cannot use SSH in a browser without an SSH extension or without an SSH tunnel client.